# How can I disable the Hover Effect for mobile devices in react js

Tags: css

I am trying to disable the hover effect for mobile devices which has a lesser than 768px and am doing it by writing media queries like the below mention but it is not working. can anyone please help me with this

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 768px){
    my className:hover {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Here's my HTML and CSS:

```css
.products {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  background: white;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  transition: 0.4s ease-out;
  box-shadow: 0px 7px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.products:hover {
  transform: translateY(-20px);
}

.products:hover:before {
  opacity: 1;
}

.products:hover .info {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0px);
}

.products:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  z-index: 2;
  transition: 0.5s;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div className="products">
  <img className="products-img shadow" src={products.img} alt="threeDimage" />
  <div class="info">
    <h1 style={{ color: "balack" }}>{products.title}</h1>
    <p>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text from the printing and typeseting industry
    </p>
    <button>Know More</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you try it using `!important` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Target only the devices that can hover using the below media query

```css
@media (hover: hover) {
  .products:hover {
    transform: translateY(-20px);
  }
  .products:hover:before {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  .products:hover .info {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  .products:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    z-index: 2;
    transition: 0.5s;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) and (hover: hover) {/* css */}, no its not working as i expected